# Search Engine Optimisation

Tags: html, optimization, seo, search-engine

I've had a look at multiple programs, scripts, plug ins etc, i'm trying to find the best one, I'd prefer a free one but if there is a decent one worth paying for then I'll use that. Just wondered if anyone had any recommendations, and what the best of optimising regarding further extension that isn't just keywords and meta tags within the original HTML files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would highly recommend reading Googles SEO guide , they have loads of hints and things to avoid getting blacklisted or ignored. And since it is Google they know what they are on about, not so much a program or script to do it for you but helpful none the less. I found it useful anyway, hopefully you will too.

[Google SEO Guide (PDF)](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf)

A lot of scripts out there will probably do some unscrupulous and nasty things to push up your search rankings which often result in you being blacklisted, this also shows what to not do which is more useful than what you should do. A lot of it is basic but theres a lot of goodness in there as well.

Comment: I've had a look through this, its pretty cool to be honest thanks, just gonna wait and see what a few others come up with too.

Comment: Yeah, I just thought it would be a handy reference document. Its also pretty, what with the pictures of robots and everthing :)

Comment: google are just epic... no questions asked

Comment: @AlexMorley-Finch No arguments here. One thing they do very very right is their documentation for developers such us as, from noob level all the way up to wizz

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any scripts or plugins that can do good SEO for you. SEO is about content, content and content.

The title of the page is important, make it short and specific. A headline (`h1` tag) is also good. The description meta tag is useful as that often is what's shown in the search result.

There are a few more things to consider, but other than that it's just content. Pages with good and unique content will be indexed well, and pages without content (or content duplicated elsewhere) will not get indexed at all.